# Firebase display integers inside a textfield in an android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show my integers saved in the firebase database in my Recyclerview. I have two Strings I can easily show in my App, but somehow it doesn't work with integers. Even more strange is that when I save a String where before there was an integer I got an error.

Here my database structure

[image]

Here I populate my Viewholder

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListItem, ListViewHolder>(

                ListItem.class,
                R.layout.card_item,
                ListViewHolder.class,

                mDatabase.orderByChild("minusAccandShare").endAt(0)
        ) {


            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ListViewHolder viewHolder, ListItem model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                viewHolder.setHeading(model.getHeading());
                viewHolder.setStoreName(model.getStoreName());
                viewHolder.setAcceptCount(model.getAcceptCount());

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putString(EXTRA_QUOTE, firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        i.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRAS, extras);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

        };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

My ViewHolder

```
public static class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView postImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).resize(200,200).into(postImage);
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading){
        TextView card_heading = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_sub_title);
        card_heading.setText(heading);
    }

    public void setStoreName(String storeName){
        TextView card_storeName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);
        card_storeName.setText(storeName);
    }

    public void setAcceptCount(String accepts){
        TextView accepts_count = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_accepts_count);
        accepts_count.setText(accepts);
    }
}
```

And finally my model

```
public class ListItem {

private String heading, storeName, image;
private Long  accepts;

public ListItem() {

}

public ListItem(String heading,String storeName, Long accepts, String image){
    this.heading = heading;
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.image = image;
    this.accepts = accepts;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}
public String getStoreName() {
    return storeName;
}
public String getImage() {return image;}
public String getAcceptCount() {
    return String.valueOf(accepts);
}
```

In this way I see null where there should stand 200 instead. I tried everything. I even saved an String instead of an integer and tried to show it the same way as the heading String ( which works perfectly) but then I see a blank place... Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a getter and setter for accepts in ListItem.

```
 public Long getAccepts() {
    return accepts;
}

public void setAccepts(Long accepts) {
    this.accepts = accepts;
}
```

Comment: I know I declared it as a Long. But it doesnt work no matter what. I cant see the mistake

Comment: I couldnt at the moment you have to wait for 5 minutes I think :D